# Want to add a custom field in craft commerce plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to add a custom field in craft commerce plugin and is it a good idea to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create new field and you can add it in it.

To add it, please go to admin panel and then follow the below mentioned sections.
settings > product type > add/select product > product fields

Then you can add custom field on field layout.

I hope this will help.